# Correlation between two variables

Tags: self-study, correlation

Qstn: X and Y have a correlation of 0.9. Does there exist another variable correlated to both X and Y  with correlation -0.9.

My answer:  yes. 
Since X and Y are correlated,

Y = a + bX ; b>0

Let there exist a variable Z correlated to both X and Y.

Then, Z = a1 + b1X ; b1<0

```
  Y = a2 + b2Z ; b2<0
```

Therefore,

Y = a2 + a1b2 +b1b2X ;b1b2>0

Please tell me if my reasoning is right?

Comment: Does Y = a + bX necessarily follow from the fact that X and Y are correlated?

Comment: Yes. Y = a+ bX is the regression equation. b, the regression coefficient depends on the sign of the correlation coefficient.

Comment: When $Z$ is correlated with $X$ and $Y$, it does not follow that $Z$ must be a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$.  However, you could *look* for such a $Z$ and if you find one, then your question will have been answered positively.

Comment: Is the part relating to the linear relation right? I have no idea on which equation to use for the non linear part?

Comment: Doesn't the question relate to linear relationship alone as it mentions "correlation coefficient"? Otherwise, wouldn't the question have said "correlation ratio "?

Comment: If $Y=a+bX$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, then $\rho_{X,Y} = 1$, not $0.9$ as you want it to be. In short, your reasoning hits a dead end right at the start.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72798/6633), there exist three random variables $X,Y,Z$ that have _identical_ covariances $\rho$, that is, $\rho_{X,Y} = \rho_{X,Z} = \rho_{Y,Z} = \rho$ for _any_  $\rho \in [-0.5,1]$ that you want to choose. So, choose $\rho = 0.9$. Now consider that random variables $X, Y$ and $-Z$ enjoy the property that $\rho_{X,Y} = 0.9; \rho_{X,-Z} = \rho_{Y,-Z} = -0.9.$

Comment: Thank you. I did not understand as to why X,Y and -Z should be taken instead of the original variables. So, would the regression equation remain the same as before?

Comment: If you use $X,Y,Z$, then $\rho_{X,Y} = \rho_{X,Z} = \rho_{Y,Z} = 0.9$, but it is _you_ who insisted that the third variable must have correlation $-0.9$ with both $X$ and $Y$. $-Z$ serves that role perfectly. If you don't like negative signs attached to random variables, then **define** $W = -Z$, then note that $\rho_{X,Y} = 0.9; \rho_{X,W} = \rho_{Y,W} = -0.9$, and so $X,Y,W$  are the three random variables you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Can i answer this question using the property that the correlation matrix should be positive semi definite?

Comment: Although correlation is *measure* of linear relationship, neither its calculation nor its interpretation require that the relationship be linear (not even approximately). You can construct examples of such nonlinear relationships using code I provided at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/152034.