# Generating data with some correlation but different dependence structure

Tags: correlation, python, independence

[image]
How would I go about generating data with the same pearson's correlation, But different dependence structure as can be seen above. Basically I want to show short coming of linear correlation as a descriptive measure of dependence.

Many Thanks

Comment: Take a rv $X$ with any centered nontrivial distribution. Then $X,X^2$ are uncorrelated but of course not independent. More counterexamples can be found by playing with or simulating copula models.

Comment: Have you looked at [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) that as four such datasets all on Wikipedia already and try [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643902?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: This question is *illustrated* in our many posts about Anscombe's quartet and *answered* (in the language of univariate regression) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152028/i-have-a-line-of-best-fit-i-need-data-points-that-will-not-change-my-line-of-be/152034#152034.  However, an answer that might best meet your needs would be one that proposes using a [copula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula+correlation).