# Generate value of variables for given correlation coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-r, deterministic

I would like to generate test data for script used for correlation analysis between quite long variables.
Is it possible for a given length of vectors, to generate in relatively simple way deterministic input data that have Pearson correlation coefficient equal almost exactly given r (e.g. 0.5,0.6.,0.7, etc.) ?

In R I tried something like the following:

```
#0.7 ---> r = 0.691

 cor(1:1000,(1:1000)^8.8)

 #0.4 ---> r = 0.39918

 cor(1:1000,(1:1000)^34.11)

 #0 ---> r = 6.526891e-06 

 cor(1:1000,sin(100*(1:1000))^9)
```

I'm looking for a (relatively) compact formula that generates such input vectors of length $n$ for given $r$ with required precision (e.g.precision=0.000001)

To simplify problem I don't care about p-value/significance.

Comment: See my answer (and code) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152028/i-have-a-line-of-best-fit-i-need-data-points-that-will-not-change-my-line-of-be/152034# for a very general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what needs to be deterministic is the correlation coefficient, you may use the option `empirical=T` option in `mvrnorm`, as in

```
library(MASS)
correlation.coeff <- 0.6
correlation.matrix <- matrix(c(1,correlation.coeff,correlation.coeff,1),ncol=2)
mu <- runif(2) # could be anything
x <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, empirical = TRUE, mu = mu, Sigma = correlation.matrix)
```

Empirical correlation is as specified:

```
> cor(x[,1],x[,2])
[1] 0.6
```

If you want the data to be reproducible, you can use `set.seed(1)`.

Why? I stripped the code of `mvrnorm` of some error and robustness checks. Note `mvrnorm.simple` is not safe to use in general.

```
mvrnorm.simple <- function (n, mu, Sigma, empirical = FALSE) {
  p <- length(mu)
  eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
  ev <- eS$values
  X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n)
  if (empirical) {
    X <- scale(X, TRUE, FALSE)
    X <- X %*% svd(X)$v
    X <- scale(X, FALSE, TRUE)
  }
  X <- mu + eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(ev), p) %*%t(X)
  t(X)
}
```

So what `empirical=T` does is to columnwise demean the $n\times p$ matrix of standard normals to get $\tilde X$, multiply with the matrix $V$ of the [singular value decomposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177102/what-is-the-intuition-behind-svd#179042) $\tilde X=UDV'$ to then scale each columns by its root mean square, see also `?scale`.

This ensures that the random draws to which the penultimate line of the code is applied have exact (up to numerical inaccuracies) *sample* means and covariances of zero and variances of one.

Comment: It would be nice to know how this option actually works, which as presented is just an uninformative black box solution.  Could you provide an explanation?

Comment: @whuber, I tried to do so, but my intuition regarding the SVD is limited.