# calculate a variance for a given R-squared

Tags: model, linear, r-squared

I am trying to replicate a study that has generating simulated data with the following variables and assumptions $x_j\sim U[0,1]$, and $j = (1,2,\dots,N)$ with

$$z_j = x_j + \sigma_z \epsilon_j$$

where, $\epsilon_j\sim N(0,1)$ and then state "we select the value $\sigma_z$ so that $R^2 = 0.75$", I believe $R^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum_j (z_j - x_j)^2}{\sum_j (z_j - \bar{z})^2}$

But I am struggling to figure how to address this problem.

Comment: What values does $j$ take?

Comment: @PascalIv I have updated, its just an index

Comment: I answered this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/152034/919, which includes code to simulate data based on the regression parameters $R^2,$ and the patterns you want to see in the residuals.

Comment: Thank you very much @whuber